# Was the fringe always there on the up-rep icon?

Tags: support, reputation, top-bar

> [image: +10 yaaaaaaaaaay!]

Today, I noticed a fringe at the bottom of the little +10 icon.  Has that always been there?  I'm not complaining, just wondering if I've failed to notice it until now.

UPDATE: I can see the fringe on Superuser and Unix & Linux sites, both of which render fonts and my profile icon smaller than other sites for some as yet unknown reason.

[image: 10 more! yaaaaaay!]

[image: and more!]

Comment: It's not a fringe on the icon, but the reputation bars icon peeking underneath.

Comment: Looks like the new top bar design has effectively rendered this issue obsolete. Now the "achievements" icon looks like a trophy, and is only about 50% obscured by the up-rep notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it was always there, and even reported by someone as a bug :)

And, as ChrisF pointed in comments, it is not fringe. It is lower part of rep indicator (I didn't know what is "fringe" until I looked in the google translate, so I just thought you understood thats bottom of rep indicator :D).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like, for some reason, your browser is rendering the rep change notification as one pixel less tall than for most of us, causing the notifications icon to peek out from underneath it.

A simple CSS fix to this problem would be:

```css
.topbar .unread-count { min-height: 11px }
```